# Motivation to hike complete PCT

Tags: hiking, pacific-crest-trail

I've been invited to hike the complete Pacific Crest Trail (PCT) with a friend. It seems like an impossible trail length of 4200km or 2600 mile that I'm doomed to fail on. But I know it could be done. What are the motivations to complete the PCT?

Comment: Have you done much long distance hiking before?

Comment: If you are asking this here, to me it feels like the PCT probably isn't right for you...

Comment: @njzk2: Only the GR340 on Belle Île On Mer (80km). Next summer I do the Tour du Mont Blanc (170km). After it I shal see.

Comment: @noah: yeah indeed I don't know what to do with the invitation. On the other side I curius about other people who has done it about there motivation.

Comment: So I've heard of longer hikes being done in small increments over many years.  When you're invited, is the assumption that it'd be done in one go ?  I don't hike much

Comment: Is it for this year? there's a _lot_ of preparation involved...

Comment: @njzk2: no, not before 2025.

Comment: Have you done much long-distance **skiing** before? The window of non-snow time is only a couple months at the north end and only 3-4 months near the south at the Sierra.They say it takes 5 months to thru-hike. https://www.pcta.org/discover-the-trail/backcountry-basics/when-to-hike-pct/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main motivation for most people will be that they have done it, that they completed something that seemed very hard to impossible.

If that is not enough to motivate you, you will have to look for things that motivate you, personally.
That can be that you reward yourself when, and only when you have finished. Maybe you can find other rewards.
It can also be the satisfaction of having helped your friend to accomplish the trail.

On the other hand, it can be that there is no way to motivate you other than starting and going on, hoping you get the hunger to finish while on the way.